# Setup OpenFrameworks for Android on Windows 7

Tags: android, openframeworks

I want to install OF for Android on My Windows 7 machine and Eclipse IDE V 4.2.

I followed the instructions in http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-setup-openframeworks-for-android-on-windows/

but I recieve the following errors upon build:

**recipe for target `AndroidRelease' failed   Makefile.android   /libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/makefileCommon   line 93**

and

**recipe for target `AndroidDebug' failed   Makefile.android   /libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/makefileCommon   line 90**

When I run an app from the examples (Polygon app) I receive the following exception from the LogCat:

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load OFAndroidApp: findLibrary returned null**

How can I solve this ?
Thanks

Comment: How to install openFrameworks for android on windows7 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMa5dla25p0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by following the steps on a fresh Eclipse IDE and cloning the **Development** branch of OpenFrameworks.